# condition for a matrix to be pseudo-hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

As we know that a matrix $H$ is said to be Hermitian if $H=H^\dagger$, and if so, then all the eigenvalues are real.

While a non-hermitian matrix $P$ is said to be pseudo-hermitian if $ \eta P \eta^{-1} =P^\dagger$, ($\eta$ is some constant metric), in this, eigenvalues may also be real.

Could anyone please throw some light that - from where this condition of pseudo-hermiticity  $ \eta P \eta ^{-1}=P^\dagger$, comes??

Comment: Check this paper. One of initial theorems. You will easily find the answer. https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00447

Comment: @ChetanWaghela, Thanks I will take a look. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with the term "pseudo-Hermitian" for such matrices (I would call them *self-adjoint* with respect to $\eta^{-1}$) but there is strong motivation for this condition: it is the natural extension of symmetry to arbitrary non-Euclidean inner products.

That is, given the inner product $\eta$, one might ask that an operator $P$ satisfy
$$\langle v, Pw\rangle_{\eta} = \langle Pv, w\rangle_{\eta}$$
for all vectors $v,w$. Unpacking this condition gives
$$w^{\dagger}P^{\dagger}\eta v = w^{\dagger}\eta P v$$
or, since equality must hold for all vectors,
$$ P^{\dagger} \eta = \eta P$$
or
$$\eta P \eta^{-1} = P^{\dagger}.$$
As a special case, you recover ordinary Hermitian matrices when $\eta=I$, and self-adjoint matrices have positive eigenvalues precisely because the spectral theorem works under any inner product.

Note that your condition is self-adjointness with respect to $\eta^{-1}$ rather than $\eta$, for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I have corrected the typo. Now it is self-adjoint with respect to $\eta$

Comment: One more ques is there: As one can show that if a matrix is  Hermitian(Self-adjoint) then its eigenvalues are ALWAYS real. Can it be shown that if it is pseudo-hermitian, then eigenvalues may also be real?

Comment: They *are* real because a pseudo-hermitian matrix (or linear mapping) is hermitian in just a different inner product. You can see that differently: Setting $A :=\eta^{1/2}$, the equality $\eta P \eta^{-1} = P^\dagger$ implies $APA^{-1} = A^{-1}P^\dagger A = (APA^{.-1})^\dagger$. So, $APA^{-1}$ is hermitian in the usual way. Thus, its eigenvalues are real. But they are the same as those of $P$.

Comment: @amsmath Thanks friend! :)

Comment: @amsmath Hi, wait wait, For $APA^{-1}$ to be Hermitian, $A$ needs to be Hermitian. Hence, in turn, $\eta$ needs to be Hermitian. Am I right ??. If so, then a pseudo-hermitian matrix will have real eigenvalues only if $A$ is Hermitian.

Comment: Since you wrote that "$\eta$ is some constant metric" I assumed that it's hermitian positive definite. That's usually what a "metric" is (defined by). So, $A = \eta^{1/2}$ is also hermitian positive definite by definition of the square root.

Comment: @amsmath thanks

Comment: @amsmath, If I take $\eta$=  {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}, then its square root: $A$={{1, 0}, {0, i}}, which is apparently not hermitian despite $\eta$ being hermitian. pl say something

Comment: @Sachin typically if you call a matrix a "metric" it will be understood that the matrix is symmetric (or Hermitian) positive-definite. Your matrix is not positive-definite.

Comment: @user7530 thanks